# Emailing passwords: Setup installed on home server using XAMPP

Tags: email, password, server, wp-mail, phpmailer

I've just delved into the WP world and all in all it's going quite well.  I have a server at home that I'm using to host the sites.  All is working fine except the password emails are not being sent when a user registers.
I've hunted quite a lot online but none of the posts that I've found relate specifically to my scenario.  Someone hints at 'all I need to do is set the correct ini options' but that's where the clues ended as the topic was closed.

My setup is using XAMPP with virtual hosts being used to redirect the URLs.

Any help is hugely appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite outdated, so I'm pretty sure no one is looking at it.  However, should anyone end up here, this question isn't really a WordPress question.

Your problem is that on a locally hosted system, you actually have to configure your stack to be able to send email.  And if you look in the outbound mail queue (XAMPP/mailoutput/), you'll probably see that emails are generated and waiting to be sent.

"sendmail" comes packaged in XAMPP, but you need to configure it.  Ideally, you'll have an SMTP server you can connect it to.  Take a look at the XAMPP FAQ under the heading [How do I send email with XAMPP?](https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_windows.html)  That tells you exactly what you need to do.

All of this has nothing to do with WordPress - it's stack configuration, which means it's really outside the scope of the WPSE site.